# EWAY payment gateway S9992 error in android

Tags: android, payment-gateway

In my app we are using eway payment gateway. As given in the documentation I have taken the Pay Now Button Public API Key from the sandbox page which begins with epk and set it to -

```
RapidAPI.PublicAPIKey=EWAY_SANDBOX_API
RapidAPI.RapidEndpoint="Sandbox";
```

Next I set the values of the card number and cvc -

```
ArrayList<NVPair> data=new ArrayList<NVPair>();
//              data.add(new NVPair("fname", fname));
//              data.add(new NVPair("lname", lname));
                data.add(new NVPair("card", cardnum));
//              data.add(new NVPair("expmonth", expMonth));
//              data.add(new NVPair("expyear", expYear));
                data.add(new NVPair("cvn", cvc));
                EncryptValuesResponse encryptedResponse = RapidAPI.encryptValues(data);
                ArrayList<NVPair> encryptedValues = encryptedResponse.getValues();
```

And encryptedResponse.getValues() returns null and encryptedResponse contains error code S9992 which the documentation states as 'Communication error with Rapid API'. which has me stumped as I have gone through the documentation a number of times but can't find where I have gone wrong or missed something.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked eWay support and they said that the API thinks the phone is not connected to the network. The app was receiving responses from other servers so this obviously wasn't the issue. I debugged this further and found that the actual error is an **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**.

I put the call to `RapidApi.encryptValues()` in a separate thread and lo and behold it works now.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        EncryptValuesResponse encryptedResponse = RapidAPI.encryptValues(data);
    }
});
thread.start();
```

The API is not doing the network call asynchronously and it is also using `org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient` which is `deprecated`. I am considering overriding the class and re-doing the network calls myself.

Comment: As an update, the eWAY Android SDK now uses `OkHttp` in place of `DefaultHttpClient` and provides methods for synchronous and async calls - documentation is available [here](https://www.eway.com.au/developers/sdk/android).

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead of using Sandbox as endpoint

```
RapidAPI.RapidEndpoint="Sandbox";
```

You should use

```
RapidAPI.RapidEndpoint="https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/";
```

Comment: This doesn't help - the eWay code translates "Sandbox" to "https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/" so you can set it to either with the same effect.